# Aspnet core (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google) and Google SSO deployed in aws EC2 with custom domain

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, amazon-ec2, single-sign-on, openid

I am doing prototype of SSO using aspnet core and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google for google SSO. It was working fine in my localhost or deploying to Azure appservice without code modification but not in EC2 using IIS and custom domain.

[image]
[image]

under google console

[image]

Here are some suggested solution I have tried as well by adding this code

- try using forwarder
- try enable all cors
- try different setting of cookie httponly, samesite and securepolicy
- removing firewall and allowng all traffic in EC2
- try Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google version 6 and 7
- try webapi or mvc web with same code
- try vs 2019 and 2022
- try this as well https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/14169

In localhost or one deployed in Azure appservice is working but not in EC2, please see image below

[image]